# How to bind dynamic function to dynamic event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery function with optional parameters, All I want is to pass control name, event name and value or function name than bind it to the passed control.

**jQuery Function**

```
BindEvents: function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        Control: null,
        Events: null
    }
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    if (Events != null) {
        $(Control).on(Events['name'], function () {
            'How to call passed function';
        });
    }
}
```

**Calling the Function**

```
$.fn.BindEvents({
    Control: "#txtTest",
    Events: { "name": "focus", "value": "$.fn.test()" }
});
```

Comment: $(Control).on(Events['name'], Function('e', Events.value));

Comment: In your line ``if (Events != null) ``, what is Events referring to? settings.Events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You forgot to use 'settings' prefix:

```
BindEvents: function (options) {
    // defaults do not make sense this way, but they probably have a sane default in your code, right?
    var defaults = {
        Control: null,
        Events: null
    }
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    if (settings.Events != null) {
        $.each(settings.Events, function(eventName, handler) {
            $(settings.Control).on(eventName, handler);
        });
    }
}
```

2) call BindEvents with an function reference instead of a string. I also changed the Event object a bit:

```
$.fn.BindEvents({
    Control: "#txtTest",
    Events: { "focus": $.fn.test }
});
```